# How can we write a jquery selector dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-selectors

I want to add some divs using jQuery in a main div called activity-div and then add a list to every div. But list items are not same for every div. So i think i need to give id to every div and then using that id i can access div and put list items in that div. i am using this jQuery code:

```
 for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
     $('#activity-div').append('<div class="area" id="area"'+i+'><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');

      }
```

Lets suppose obj.length is 5. Then 5 divs will be added. and their id's will be area1, area2, area3, area4 and area5. My question is how can i get these divs by id using a loop. I know that a div can be accessed using this:

```
   ('#area1').append('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

i want to access all divs i created using the loop and then add list in that. How can i do that? what will be the syntax for that? I tried

```
 ('#area'+i).append('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

but it didn't work. I am new to jQuery and couldn't find any online help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `('#area'+i)` is the correct syntax, check the value of `i` if it gives you any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#area'+i).append();` should work!

You do have an error in your code:

```
append('<div class="area" id="area"'+i+'><h3>
```

should be:

```
append('<div class="area" id="area'+i+'"><h3>
```

Comment: +1 just because i wanted to get your rep away from 1337 ;P oh and you have a right answer :)  http://i.imgur.com/MhcIh.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `for` loop, the `id` attribute isn't adding the numeric value to it correctly.

With your current code it'll come out `id="area"1` rather then `id="area1"`

This is the correct code:

```
$('#activity-div').append('<div class="area" id="area'+i+'"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
```

Also just to add more to this your append lines at the bottom are missing the jQuery `$` identifier and should look like

```
$('#area1').append('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a better practice to build your DOM insertions into a string and add them all at the same time. You also had an error in your code where the ID was added to the DIV. Try this:

```
var insertion = "";
for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    insertion += '<div class="area" id="area'+i+'"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>';
}
$('#activity-div').append( insertion );
```

Comment: +1, this is a very good suggestion. I believe older browsers are faster with pushing data into an array and then joining the array at the end: `var insertion = []; for(...) {insertion.push(...);} $('#activity-div').append( insertion.join('') );`

Answer (score 2):

Skip the id altogether and just select by class and index:

```
$("#activity-div .area").eq(i).append("<ul><li></li></ul>");
```

Or, better yet, skip the unnecessary jQuery lookup and just keep a reference to the elements.

```
var areas = [];
for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
    var area = $('<div class="area"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
    $('#activity-div').append(area);
    areas.push(area);
}
```

Then access the area by index:

```
areas[i].append("<ul><li></li></ul>");
```

If it is possible to combine your loops into one, this would be ideal:

```
for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
    var area = $('<div class="area"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
    area.append("<ul><li></li></ul>");
    $('#activity-div').append(area);
}
```

But, none of those solutions really does it for you - nowhere are you actually adding list items.  I'd iterate `obj` using `$.each`, and then append the list items in the same loop, avoiding looping twice.  How about this, assuming your list items are also contained in `obj[i]`:

```
$.each(obj, function () {
    var list = $('<div class="area"><h3><a href="#">'+this.name+'</a></h3><ul></ul></div>')
        .appendTo("#activity-div")
        .find("ul");
    $.each(this.listItems, function () {
        list.append("<li>" + this.Name + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also select all of the `id=area<num>` divs with a jQuery selector:

```
$('div[id^="area"]').append('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

This selects all the `div` elements with id's that start with "area" and appends a `ul` element to it.

Docs for jQuery selectors can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: but every div will have different amount of list items. area1 can have 5, area2 can have 3. Does this work for that as well?

Comment: `$('div[id^="area"]')` will select any element in the DOM that has an id that starts with "area". So "area1" through "area5" will work, as well as "area_not_5" and "area_to_calculate". So this style of selector only works if no other objects have ids that start with "area". You can start with a container element to eliminate selecting elements like "area_not_5": `$('#activity-div').find('div[id^="area"]')...` It appears as though the area divs are direct children of the `activity-div` element so you can use: `$('#activity-div').children('div[id^="area"]')...` which will perform faster.

Answer (score 1):

> Lets suppose obj.length is 5. Then 5 divs will be added. and their id's will be area1, area2, area3, area4 and area5...

Incorrect. Take a look at your code here:

```
for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  $('#activity-div').append('<div class="area" id="area"'+i+'><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
}
```

If there are 5 `obj`ects, they will be numbered according to `i`. In a `for` loop, you're getting the values 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, since `i++` does not occur until the last step before the loop repeats (that is, the evaluation of `i<obj.length` occurs before the loop, and `i++` occurs after).

Barring the problem with your `id="area"'+i+'` (this should be `id="area'+i+'"`), if you're expecting values from 1 to 5, adjust your for loop accordingly:

```
for( i=1; i<=obj.length; i++ ) {
  $('#activity-div').append('<div class="area" id="area'+i+'"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
}
```

If you then wish to add the list, you could do:

```
for( i=1; i<=obj.length; i++ ) {
  $('#activity-div').append('<div class="area" id="area'+i+'"><h3><a href="#">'+obj[i].name+'</a></h3></div>');
  $('#area'+i).append('<ul><li></li></ul');
}
```

There is no real reason to create a second for loop, and the placement should attempt to append to `$('#area'+i)` only after its creation. If you have issues, using firefox with firebug may help. You can add lines such as:

```
console.log( i );
```

To the `for` loop to track the value of i as it increments through the stages.